Is there a tool to add stripes to a THHN wire as you pull it?
I know it is possible to order THHN wire that is already striped with another color for identification in the conduit, but I wonder if there is a tool that (for example) mounts a sharpie to the wire, so it can be striped (not stripped) when it is pulled.
First example, it would be nice to stripe the neutral white with the color hot conductor that pairs the neutral in the conduit. If something like this exists then I would like to know what it is called.

I know of no tool, but nothing prevents you from marking the wire before you put it in the conduit.

Quite a few pictures showing just the ends with coloured tape, to show what is what.  Think they save the stripe wire for fancy folks.

It's called "ordering the correct striped wire if you have that much use for it" and otherwise you use tape as mentioned by @crip659. Indeed, you normally tape the correct neutral TO the correct hot, as well as color coding its end. The proposed machine sounds like the sort of thing that would prove to be problematic in actual use, and that means the efficient use of an electrician's time is served by having the striped wire on hand, not fussing with a balky striping machine during a pull.

@Ecnerwal  I guess that is what the packs of multi-colour tape is for.

I have many colors on hand, (not green, not pink.) No point in green unless you are running insulated grounds over 4 gauge, and pink seems to be less common on the shelf for whatever reason. If I see a roll of pink I'll probably buy it.

Aside: A trick I've used when pulling wires when there are only pairs in a color to keep straight is to reverse one length of wire in each pair before pulling. The markings on the wire will read in opposite directions and can be readily distinguished after pulling. It's still a good idea to follow up with colored tape or some other marking after the pull for the benefit of those who come along later.

Yeah, the problem is there are 8 hot colors but only 2 neutral colors.

Here are two markers, one for full and one for stripes marking

Found here
Wire marking felt pen
For stripes use this pen

